# Switching between scenes in Phaser3

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework, game-development

So I have two scenes in my **Phaser3** (version in `package.json` is **3.21.0**) app and I would like to switch between those without having any side-effect. The first scene is for handling the menu with high score and the second is the game itself.

**Related code**

The `app.ts` file looks like the following:

```
const config = {
    title: '<game-name>',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    parent: 'game',
    scene: [MenuScene, GameScene],
};

export class GameName extends Phaser.Game {
    constructor(config: any) {
        super(config);
    }
}

window.onload = () => new GameName(config);
```

The `MenuScene.ts` - removed the inapplicable part:

```
class MenuScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() { super({key: 'MenuScene'}); }

    create():void {
       console.log('create menuscreen');
       const enter = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.ENTER);
       enter.on('down', () => { this.scene.start('GameScene'); }
    }
}
```

The `GameScene.ts` - also removed the unrelated code snippets:

```
class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() { super({key: 'GameScene'}); }

    create = ():void => {
       console.log('create gamescreen');
       const esc = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.ESC);
       esc.on('down', () => { this.scene.start('MenuScene'); }
    }
}
```

**The issue and my question**

So once I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> repetitively just to switch with the provided solution, it does not seems to be cleaning up the scenes in the background. On the `console` I see the following after switching few times (in the below example 6 times):
[image: console-screenshot]

I have already tried calling `this.scene.stop()` before `this.scene.start('<scene-key>')` but still the same issue. I was reading the [Phaser3 Scenes transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238869/phaser3-scenes-transitions) question already and it does not seem to answer my question. There has been told the `start()` should clean up or shut down the not used one.

So how should I switch between scenes properly or cleaning up the currently not used scene?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i am doing it

**1.- Scene over game for pause**

The scene `scene_pause` will be over the `game_scene` because the last scene will be the top scene

```js
isPaused = this.scene.isPaused('scene_game');
if (false === isPaused) {
    this.scene.pause('scene_game');
}
const isNull = this.scene.get('scene_pause');
if (null === isNull) {
    this.scene.add('pause_scene', PauseScene, true);
}
```

And then when y resume the game

```js
isActive = this.scene.isActive('scene_pause');
if (true === isActive) {
    this.scene.remove('scene_pause');
}
isPaused = this.scene.isPaused('scene_game');
if (true === isPaused) {
    this.scene.resume('scene_game');
}
```

---

**2.- Switch scene for game over**

```js
this.scene.stop('scene_game'); // stop executing the Update 1rst
... // save the state and score
this.scene.remove('scene_game'); // I remove the scene, because I will add again when start the game
this.scene.stop('scene_ui');
this.scene.switch('scene_game_over');
```

Comment: So I applied `add` if not exists and `remove` after started the other scene which did the trick.Thanks for the help!